# Match two values in one sheet with two values in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

The goal is to find the matching entries

- from Sheet1 column A (ID) & column D (value)
  [image]
- with Sheet2 column A (ID) & column D (value)
  [image]

Returning the matching value from the two sheets in column E in sheet1

Sheet 1 has additional add-ins
Sheet 2 stays constant

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D3:D8,MATCH(SHEET2!$A3,SHEET1!$A3:A8,0)),"Additional Value")
```

Comment: You can run MATCH() on 2 columns: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html

Comment: I am confused on exactly what you are wanting to return and on what criteria is the match.  You want to match on the ID and Value, and return the Value?  So the first would match on the `1` and the `5` and return `5`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the comment - Yes, exactly.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use COUNTIFS with IF:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(SHEET1!$A$3:$A$8,SHEET2!$A3,SHEET1!$A$3:$A$8,SHEET2!$D3),SHEET2!$D3,"Additional Value")
```

This will check if a match exists, if so it just returns the value, if not it returns your string.

Comment: The formula return the string for all existing matches

Comment: Then look to the data:  1.  Make sure all the references are correct.  2.  Make sure you have absolute references where needed. 3.  Make sure the data truly matches.  This expects EXACT matches.